# protractor-screenshot-reporter does not create folder if all the test pass and 'captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true' is enabled

Tags: protractor

protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter does not create folder if all the test pass and Config file has 'captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true' is enabled

Config File:

```
 exports.config = {

  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
  suites: {
  full: 'e2e/**/*.js'   
  }, 
multiCapabilities: [
 {'browserName': 'chrome'}
],
directConnect : true,  

baseUrl: 'http://mytesturl:8080/',


framework: 'jasmine2',

jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},  
onPrepare: function() {   
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
        var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter'); 
        var reporter =  new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
                dest: 'tests/test-results/screenshots',
                filename: 'E2E-report.html',                 
                showSummary: true,
                showQuickLinks: true,                
                captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
                pathBuilder: function(currentSpec, suites, browserCapabilities) {
                       return browserCapabilities.get('browserName') + '/' + currentSpec.fullName;
                 },
             });    
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
   });    
  },      
};
```

if All the Test Passes and /screenshots folder does not exists then it does not creates /screenshots folder.
If the Test Fails and /screenshots is not present, reporter creates /screenshots folder and saves the screenshots and html report under this folder.

I am getting following error if all the test passes and /screenshots folder is not present:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ui\dgui\tests\test-results\screenshots\E2E-report.html'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1156:15)
at Object.fs.appendFileSync (fs.js:1204:6)
at Jasmine2ScreenShotReporter.jasmineDone (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter\index.js:499:10)
at dispatch (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1869:28)
at C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1852:11
at QueueRunner.clearStack (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:605:9)
at QueueRunner.run (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1784:12)
at C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1801:16
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().window().maximize()
at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:362:15)
at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.Window.maximize (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:1476:23)
at exports.config.onPrepare (C:\ui\dgui\tests\protractor-conf-IncidentPanel.js:73:35)
at C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\lib\util.js:56:41
at Function.promise (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:650:9)
at Object.exports.runFilenameOrFn_ (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\lib\util.js:46:12)
at [object Object].Runner.runTestPreparer (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:76:17)
at Object.exports.run (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\lib\frameworks\jasmine2.js:89:17)
at C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:333:35
at _fulfilled (C:\ui\dgui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: can you share your full config file? and which version of protractor /reporter are you using?

Comment: Here is my config file ,  i am using protractor-jasmine2-reporter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like someone already posted an issue on their github: https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/issues/65

I was able to fix this problem by downgrading to protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter@0.2.0